# If $a<b$ and $c<d$, when is $ac<bd$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $a<b$ and $c<d$, when is $ac<bd$ true?

I know that it is true when $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are all positive.

But are there other cases that $ac<bc$ is true?

Can it be true when $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are all negative?

Comment: You're right that it's true when the numbers are all positive, and you're right to be suspicious in other cases. Play around with a few number examples yourself, and you should quickly find a counterexample. As for your final question, here's a hint: if $a, b, c, d$ are negative, then $-a, -b, -c, -d$ are all positive. Also, $a < b$ implies $-b < -a$. Can you see why the conclusion will always be false in this case?

Comment: Assuming no number is null , each number can be either strictly positive or strictly negative. Hence $2\times 2\times 2\times 2$ cases to consider. Maybe one can begin by " all 4 positive" and " all 4 negative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a, b, c, and d are all negative than it is true that:

$|a|>|b|$ and $|c|>|d|$ and because negative times negative is positive, it is also true that $ac > bd$. Which means there are no solutions with all negative numbers.

If either a and c or b and d are negative the same inequality holds as if all values were positive (because negative times negative is positive).

If either b or d are negative the inequality is always true (because bd is negative and ac is positive) and if either a or c are negative it is never true (the opposite).

If three values are negative and either b or d are positive it is always true (because bd is negative and ac is positive) and if either a or c are positive it is never true (the opposite).

When a or c is zero than bd has to be smaller than 0. If either b or d is zero, ac has to be bigger than 0.

That are all the possibilities.